# Display table with dynamic columns based on List<Object[]>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, dynamic-columns

I have a `List<Object[]>`, how can I display this in a `<h:dataTable>` with dynamic columns? I can also use a `List<List<Object>>` if necessary.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) which you can get from [`getMetaData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29).

Comment: maybe I'm not quite clear in my question, let me revise it...